# How can i generate an image based on HTML DOM + video?

Tags: javascript, camera, navigator

i'm making a "instagram filter" app on web, and i'm using this HTML + JS structure to load the camera on the video element:

```
<div id="camera" class="camera" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative">
    <video style="object-fit: cover"></video>
        <div class="chuva-canvas">
            <div id="c1" class="item"></div>
            <div id="c2" class="item"></div>
            <div id="c3" class="item"></div>
        </div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <img id="img_val" src="" alt="">
</div>
```

```
startCamera() {
        var constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: {
                facingMode: {
                    exact: 'environment'
                }
            }
        };

        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        navigator.getUserMedia(
            // constraints
            constraints,

            // success callback
            function (mediaStream) {
                let video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
                try {
                    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
                } catch (error) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
                }
                video.play();
                this.startActions();
            },
            //handle error
            function (error) {
                alert('Não conseguimos encontrar uma câmera disponível.');
            });
    }
```

The image looks nice, and on my "chuva-canvas" div, the filter is already loading and working fine.

All i need is, when the user press download, he get's a JPG/PNG with all of this.

I already tried to use html2canvas, but the video doesn't render on this, i only got the empty background + filter.

I'm using download.js to download the image and works fine, but i can generate a base64 with video + filter.

Do you know any way to do this?